# scrollComponentToVisible not working as intended

Tags: codenameone

I am building a basic chat application, that has text boxes on the right for your own messages and on the left for any other participants messages. Each message is in a row of the Box Layout Y_Axis container. 
After a new message is posted, I want the latest message to be visible, hence I thought I would use scrollComponentToVisible on the container with the message boxes (labels). However, no matter what I give as a parameter, it just scrolls up to the very top of the container. Which means, the container is scrollable and the command does something, however it scrolls up, rather than down to what I want to see.

Code snippet:

```
            // chat history
            Container chatHistory = new Container(new BoxLayout(BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
            chatHistory.setScrollableY(true);
            hi.add(BorderLayout.CENTER, chatHistory);

            ...

            // send button and action event for sending message
            sendButton.addActionListener(e ->{

                chatHistory.add(FlowLayout.encloseRight(new Label(chatInput.getText(), null, "chatOwn"))); // TODO word wrap text
                chatInput.setText("");

                Label newMessage = new Label("auto response", null, "chatOther");
                chatHistory.add(FlowLayout.encloseLeftMiddle(newMessage));


                // this is where the magic should happen 
                chatHistory.scrollComponentToVisible(newMessage);
            });
```

I do know about the smooth scrolling that I need to set to false while scrolling, but left that out of the code to keep it as short as possible.

Any tips on what is wrong here are appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you add a component it's in 0,0 and sized 0,0. So it's working exactly as expected...

You need to revalidate (or animate layout) and only after that completed would scroll to visible work. Revalidate is immediate so that's easy, just use `callSerially()` to postpone the scroll after the revalidate.

Comment: As always, your answers are insightful and to the point. I added a simple "hi.revalidate();" AFTER adding the new component for it to get the proper position within the form and BEFORE calling the scrollComponentToVisible command. Works perfectly.